# run cron on ssh, error message

Tags: ssh, cron, putty

how to run the script below

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://example.com/scheduler/cron"
```

when i run the script, the error message show as below:

```
$ * * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://website.com/?q=admin/settings/scheduler/cron"
-sh: CHANGELOG.txt: not found
$ 30 15 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://website.com/?q=admin/settings/scheduler/cron"
-sh: 30: not found
```

can the script above run in ssh (using putty software)

Answer (score 1):

Crontab files are not scripts. They're configuration files for cron, which runs commands periodically. The first five fields of a line specify the schedule, the rest of the line specifies the command to run at those times. See `man crontab` for how to submit or edit your personal crontab.

Comment: go to terminal and do 
crontab -e

[code]
Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#

# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
[/code]

http://i.imgur.com/aFg8C.jpg

is that add
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://example.com/scheduler/cron"
on file above?

if yes, how to save the file?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your terminal and do

```
crontab -e
```

which will ask you for editor options. select VIM or whichever you are comfortable with.
paste this there.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://example.com/scheduler/cron"
```

save the file and then things should work

Redirect your commands output to see if things are working. Like this

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://example.com/scheduler/cron" >> /home/../asd.log 2>&!
```

Comment: Go to your terminal and do 
crontab -e

Comment: what happened ?

Comment: go to terminal and do <br/>
crontab -e<br/>
<br/><br/>

Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.<br/>
#<br/>

# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts<br/>
# at 5 a.m every week with:<br/>
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/<br/>
<br/><br/>

http://i.imgur.com/aFg8C.jpg<br/>

is that add<br/>
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://example.com/scheduler/cron"
on file above?<br/>

if yes, how to save the file?<br/>

Comment: littlecegian , sorry, i thought i reply here can add break line, it looks messy here. i have add one more reply below. please take a look there...

Comment: hey there. The editor from the screenshot is called nano. Hence VI commands wont work in there. It is a simple editor. Open the file. Go to the place type the characters. ctrl+s to save. ctrl+x to close. check this out if you have any doubts http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/reu/nano.html. ^x means ctrl+x. cheers

Answer (score 0):

go to terminal and do 
crontab -e

and it redirect to this：

```
Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.

#

# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
```

see the attachment image below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnWGJ.jpg

is that add the code on file above?
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://example.com/scheduler/cron"
on file above?

if yes, how to save the file?
i have press "vi" and press escape, but not working.